# Kotlin Compose global footer view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to show an *Ad banner* at the bottom which is globally displayed. That means that I want to stick there when I navigate throughout the app.
So far I've tried adding the `NavHost` and the `AdView` inside a `Column`, hoping that the navigation with the linked pages will just take the remaining space and the bottom view will stick there. However the `NavHost` takes the whole screen and the `AdView` has zero height. When I navigate the second view, the `AdView` is still inside the view hierarchy but still with zero height.

I've tried changing all kinds of setup, adding `.weight(1f)` to the Ad view, changing Column Arrangement, `.fillMaxSize()`, `.fillMaxHeight()`, `.minHeight()`, fixed height, etc.

I might need to look into different layout for achieving this result, but not sure in which direction to search. The Ad works well, I tried displaying without the column and is shown correctly in the center of the screen.

Another variant I've tried is to display it without column, add bottom spacing to the `NavHost` then position the `AdView` to the bottom somehow. With this variant I haven't been able to position it to bottom.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Column() {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = NavigationRoutes.Home
                ) {
                    composable(NavigationRoutes.Home) { HomeView(navController = navController) }
                    composable(
                        NavigationRoutes.Books,
                        arguments = listOf(navArgument("mode") { type = NavType.IntType })
                    ) { backStackEntry ->
                        val rawMode = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("mode") ?: 0
                        var mode: ContentMode = if (rawMode == 0) {
                            ContentMode.READING
                        } else {
                            ContentMode.QUIZ
                        }
                        BooksView(navController = navController, mode = mode)
                    }
                }
                AndroidView(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
                        .weight(1f),
                    factory = { context ->
                        AdView(context).apply {
                            setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
                            adUnitId = AdIdentifiers.GlobalBanner.adID
                            loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the issue of any child Composable of NavHost having Modifier.fillmaxSize(). You can set a Modifier for NavHost which let's you define how much space it will cover

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){

   NavHost(modifier = Modifier.fillmaxWidth).weight(1f){}
   AdView(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
   )
           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put AndroidView in Box and give androidView height as bottom padding values in screens.

```
NavHost(
    //
){
    //
}
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
){
    AndroidView()
}
```

Comment: This one works too! I went with Thracian's answer as I think it encapsulates better the views with the column. It avoids having to do padding for the NavHost. Thanks, upvoted!